# Apache2 ProxyPass for Rails App Gitlab

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, apache2, proxypass

I am attempting to setup a proxy with Apache2 so that incoming requests to **http://myipaddress.com** go to `http://localhost:3000/` where I have Gitlab ( a rails app ) running. The following is what I have in my Apache configuration file on Ubuntu 10.04. I can successfully access the gitlab default page initially, but any subsequent requests performed by me by clicking on other pages after that go to a 404 NOT FOUND page. I can manually enter /gitlab/ in front of any of these failed redirects and they work just fine. How can I make this work without having to rewrite /gitlab/ after each redirect request after the initial request?

```
## Setup a proxy which listens on the port that gitlabh does ( from start_server.sh )
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/
#DocumentRoot /home/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/public
<Proxy http://localhost:3000/>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

I understand that I could have the code below , which would solve my problem. But I don't know how to modify the prefix of the gitlab rails service. I'd really appreciate some help!

```
ProxyPass /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/gitlab/
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/gitlab/
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to Friek's comment I've come very close to solving this. Below is part of my http.conf file. The only problem is when I hit the home button or the logo on the gitlab app it attempts to redirect to gitlab/ which gives me the basic index.html file from Apache2 saying 'it works!'. How can I configure this to allow me to simply got /gitlab and it takes me to the root home view of gitlab?? Thanks!

```
## For Gitlab using Apache2 Passenger
## Install on Ubuntu by:
## sudo gem install passenger && sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
## but only after running the install_and_configure_git.py script
## and creating a soft link to the rails gitlab /public directory like so:
## sudo ln -s /home/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/public /var/www/gitlab
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.13
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName gitlab

        ## Set the overall Document Root
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www>
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ## Set the Rails Base URI
        RackBaseURI /gitlab
        RailsBaseURI /gitlab
        <Directory /var/www/gitlab>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've been trying to do something very similar here, and came across this. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/642 Seems this functionality is not and probably won't be included in gitlab.

Comment: Why don't you install the apache passenger module (gem install passenger && passenger-install-apache2-module) and point the documentroot of a new virtual host to <path to gitlab>/public? Works beautifully for me..

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, check out my new info posted above.

Comment: Hey @phil999, just wanted to tell you that at least what you wrote down above is at least insecure from what the passenger documentation sais. You should point the directory to `<rails_app_path>/public` instead. EDIT: Just seen that you linked correctly... maybe you should somehow make that bold for blinds like me... :/ Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3689615) that worked for me. In case it ever goes dead, I'll repost it.

---

#### unicorn config file

Edit file `/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb`

Find line listen `"#{app_dir}/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket"` and comment it. Uncomment line listen `"127.0.0.1:8080"`

#### required modules for apache

- sudo a2enmod proxy
- sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
- sudo a2enmod proxy_http
- sudo a2enmod rewrite

#### /home/gitlab/gitlab/config/gitlab.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.domain.com

  # Point this to your public folder of teambox
  DocumentRoot /home/gitlab/gitlab

  RewriteEngine On

  <Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
  </Proxy>

  # Redirect all non-static requests to thin
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  # Custom log file locations
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have modified /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf and added Alias /gitlab "/var/www/gitlab" with directory directive. When I try to access it via example.com/gitlab it does not work / does not load homepage but example.com/gitlab/deploy.html works well. How to access Gitlab first page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName gitlab

        ## Set the overall Document Root
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www>
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ## Set the Rails Base URI
        RackBaseURI /gitlab
        RailsBaseURI /gitlab
        <Directory /var/www/gitlab>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

These settings in your httpd.conf or your sites config file should do., Please remove the reverse proxy settings if you have any and try, it will work.,

if you have below lines along with above config, please remove the below lines,

```
ProxyPass /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/gitlab/
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab/ http://localhost:3000/gitlab/
Proxy on
```

Restart your webserver

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in case someone new comes across this issue.

This helped me, notice the **ProxyPassReverse** lines. My full issue and resolution is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390543/3112527 .

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Servername gitlab.my_domain.com
  ServerAdmin my_admin@my_domain.com

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/gitlab_my_domain.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/gitlab_my_domain_private.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/gitlab.ca-bundle

  ##### All the other Apache SSL setup skipped here for StackOverflow ####

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    # For relative URL root "host:your_gitlab_port/relative_root"
    #ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8085/gitlab
    #ProxyPassReverse https://gitlab.my_domain.com/gitlab

    # For non-relative URL root
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8085
    ProxyPassReverse https://gitlab.my_domain.com/
  </Location>

  # apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  LogFormat  "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog      /var/log/apache2/gitlab-ssl_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab-ssl_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab-ssl_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab-ssl.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

(from https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-ssl-apache2.4.conf)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here while Googling for errors I encountered while setting up Rails + unicorn using Apache (on port 80) to proxy to unicorn (on port 3000). In case it's of use to anyone else, here's my config:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Location />
      Require all granted
      ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:3000
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://example.com:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  DocumentRoot /home/user/rails-dir/public
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /home/user/rails-dir/log/apache-error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/rails-dir/log/apache-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question also troubles me quite a long time. It's fixed now.
The most helpful resource is from the Gitlab official document about [using-a-non-bundled-web-server](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server).
They also provide full workable [recipe](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache).

> If you are using Apache version 2.4 or above, please use files
>   gitlab-apache24.conf or gitlab-ssl-apache24.conf for the HTTP and
>   HTTPS versions of the vhost repectively.
>
> If you are using Apache version 2.2, please use files
>   gitlab-apache22.conf or gitlab-ssl-apache22.conf for the HTTP and
>   HTTPS versions of the vhost repectively.

The problem now simple to

> Make sure you pick the right configuration file depending whether you
>   choose to serve GitLab with SSL or not. The only thing you need to
>   change is `YOUR_SERVER_FQDN` with your own FQDN and if you use SSL, the
>   location where your SSL keys currently reside. You also might need to
>   change the location of your log files.

to make sure the Apache2 version, use `apache2 -version`
If use HTTPS version, you may need to make sure your cert file is deployed correctly e.g. the files are placed consistent with recipe file specified.