# How to configure nginx to serve gitlabhq on a SubURI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gitlab

The nginx configuration for gitlab is:

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 3.0

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen YOUR_SERVER_IP:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name YOUR_SERVER_FQDN;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

What should i change to serve gitlab as a surURI, www.mysuperserver.com/gitlab

i've tried many different things, but nothing worked
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Gitlab 5.3 you can configure it to run in a suburi out of the box using the official installation document.

Uncomment line 8 of config/puma.rb:
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/"

Similarly for line 23 in config/gitlab.yml:
relative_url_root: /

I didn't have to modify my nginx config at all for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully made it working under a subdir url.

- follow the instruction in the source code, like in `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml`

```
    # Uncomment and customize the last line to run in a non-root path
    # WARNING: We recommend creating a FQDN to host GitLab in a root path instead of this.
    # Note that four settings need to be changed for this to work.
    # 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
    # 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
    # 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
    # 4) In ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url: "http://127.0.0.1/gitlab"
    # To update the path, run: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
    #
    relative_url_root: /gitlab
```

- change the nginx config to serve a suburi, plz refer to my example below:

The key point is the `root` under context `server` and `alias` under `location`. Plz refer to [nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls), [nginx root note](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) for more details.

```
# default.conf for nginx
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  $YOUR_DOMAIN;
    # other settings, especially root settings, like below
    # root /usr/local/nginx/html;
    location /gitlab {
        # serve static files from defined root folder;
        alias /home/git/gitlab/public;

        # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

        # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
    }

    location @gitlab {
        proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
    # other locations' settings...
}
```

Comment: +1. what version of GitLab did you use? Did you test it with push/pull ssh url? https url?

Comment: branch `6-4-stable`. nobody complains about the push/pull. not setup the https url yet.

Answer (score 2):

For old versions, for example, gitlab 7.4.5 , there is no gitlab-git-http-server (gitlab-workhorse). But there are some solutions for gitlab 7.4.5 to use suburi in the doc.

[config/application.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-4-stable/config/application.rb)

```
# Relative url support
# Uncomment and customize the last line to run in a non-root path
# WARNING: We recommend creating a FQDN to host GitLab in a root path instead of this.
# Note that following settings need to be changed for this to work.
# 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
# 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
# 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
# 4) In ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url: "http://127.0.0.1/gitlab"
# 5) In lib/support/nginx/gitlab : do not use asset gzipping, remove block starting with "location ~ ^/(assets)/"
#
# To update the path, run: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
#
# config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
```

[config/gitlab.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-4-stable/config/gitlab.yml.example)

```
# WARNING: See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
# other files that need to be changed for relative url support
# relative_url_root: /gitlab
```

Configuring gitlab 7.4.5 with other website using same port and same domain name in a nginx configuration or apache configuration file seems still a challenge. I did not get this. I can access gitlab as www.mydomain.com/gitlab , but I did not get my another website in another root directory with www.mydomain.com. It should be resoved by configure nginx or apache. Hope people who are familiar with nginx or apache can give a solution.

Other references.[Support installing GitLab in a relative URL path or sub directory #1950](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1950)

**EDIT**
**It works now.**

stackoverflow suggest to use www.example.com as example here.

www.example.com/gitlab access gitlab.

www.example.com access another website, say, my blog.

Steps:

1. config/application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
2. config/gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
3. config/unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
4. ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url: `"http://www.example.com/gitlab"`
5. copy lib/support/nginx/gitlab to gitlab.conf for nginx and do not use asset gzipping, remove block starting with `"location ~^/(assets)/"`
6. run: sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:precompile
   RAILS_ENV=production

Urls:

1. config/gitlab.yml file: host: example.com port: 80
2. config/unicorn.rb: listen "127.0.0.1:9095"
3. ../gitlab-shell/config.yml: gitlab_url:
           `http://www.example.com/gitlab`

gitlab will give git two way to access:

1. git@example.com:sample-project.git
2. http://example.com/gitlab/sample-project.git

I am not using https.

If you got:

- git@example.com/gitlab:sample-project.git
- http://example.com/gitlab/gitlab/sample-project.git

You might configure `config/gitlab.yml` as `host: example.com/gitlab`. Just remove the `/gitlab`.

nginx configuration file:

```
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################
##

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

## Normal HTTP host
server {
  #listen *:80 default_server;
  listen *:80 default_server;
  server_name www.example.com; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  #root /home/git/gitlab/public;
  root html;
  location /{
    #root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  ## Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  ## Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  logs/example.gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   logs/example.gitlab_error.log;

  location /gitlab {
    alias /home/git/gitlab/public;

    ## Serve static files from defined root folder.
    ## @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below.
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  ## If a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  ## then the proxy passes the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn).
  location @gitlab {
    ## If you use HTTPS make sure you disable gzip compression
    ## to be safe against BREACH attack.
    # gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  #location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
  #  root /home/git/gitlab/public;
  #  #gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
  #  expires max;
  #  add_header Cache-Control public;
  #}

  error_page 502 /502.html;
}
```

Apache(2.2.9) configuration file:  Reference [gitlab.conf](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/apache-old/web-server/apache/gitlab.conf) for gitlab 6.0.6 and [gitlab-8.0-apache2.2.conf](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/apache-old/web-server/apache/gitlab-8.0-apache2.2.conf) for gitlab 8.0.0 on apache 2.2

```
#  Module dependencies
#  mod_rewrite
#  mod_proxy
#  mod_proxy_http
<VirtualHost *:80>


  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  DocumentRoot "/data/webapp/www/wordpress"

  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  #ErrorLog "logs/wordpress-error_log"
  #CustomLog "logs/wordpress-access_log" common

    #SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/data/webapp/www/ZendFramework-2.3.3/library"
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory /data/webapp/www/wordpress>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  #ServerName www.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location /gitlab>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9095
    ProxyPassReverse http://www.example.com//

    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:9095%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]
  </Location>

  #apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  #  RewriteEngine on
  #  RewriteCond /code/gitlab/{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  #  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:9095%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  #DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public
  Alias /gitlab /home/git/gitlab/public
  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog  logs/example.com_error.log
  CustomLog logs/example.com_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog logs/example.com_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog logs/example.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you resolved this issue yet?

If not, try updating the `location /` directive to:

```
location /gitlab {
  # serve static files from defined root folder;.
  root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;
  # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}
```

If that doesn't work, please paste the last few lines of `/var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log`.

Comment: I have a similar problem to the original question, and I tried your approach to solving it. My error log doesn't have any new entries in it, and it appears that this alone doesn't solve the problem. What I'm  trying to do is apply your suggestion to something like this: http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/nginx.conf.

Answer (score -1):

This configuration works

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 3.0

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; 37.59.125.28:
  server_name gitlab.<YOUR_DOMAIN>.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

And I had a bad symbolic link between nginx available configuration and the enabled configuration.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing the difference between your config and the one in your question (except for the server name). Where is the part which allows for `www.mysuperserver.com/gitlab`?

Comment: The above config appears to be for a subdomain. My answer, although untested, should work for the question as it was asked, `www.mysuperserver.com/gitlab`. If anyone tries it, it would be good to get confirmation.