# How to use robots.txt with gitlab and apache + subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost, robots.txt, gitlab

I can't access my robots.txt (locally located at /home/git/gitlab/public/robots.txt)
I Followed [this recipe](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos)  for installation on centos + apache

I've already tried to exclude robots.txt but this wasnt enough
This is my current VirtualHost for gitlab

```
<VirtualHost git.domain.tld:80>                                              
   ServerName git.domain.tld
   ServerSignature Off                                                    
   ProxyPreserveHost On                                                         

  <Location />                                                                  
    Order deny,allow                                                            
    Allow from all                                                              

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080                                      
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.domain.tld/
  </Location>                                                                   

  #apache equivalent of nginx try files                                         
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files                                                                      
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab        

RewriteEngine on                                                              

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                          

  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]                    
  # needed for downloading attachments                                          
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public                                          


  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.                                           
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html                                                   
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html                                                   
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html                                                   
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html                                                

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded       
  ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/logs/gitlab_error.log           
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded           
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog         
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/gitlab.log combined                             
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart` after you added the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

try to change
/home/git/gitlab/config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
(it's false by default)