# GitLab 7.2.1 with Apache Server instead of Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, gitlab

I have installed GitLab `7.2.1` with the .deb package from [GitLab.org](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads) for Debian 7 on a virtual server where I have root access.
On this virtual server I have already installed Apache, version `2.2.22` and I don't want to use Ngnix for GitLab.

Now I have no idea where the public folders of GitLab are or what I have to do or on what I have to pay attention.

So my question is: How do I have to configure my vhost for apache or what do I have to do also that I can use a subdomain like "gitlab.example.com" on my apache web server?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With two things in mind:

1. Unicorn is listening on 8080 (you can check this with `sudo netstat -pant | grep unicorn`)
2. Your document root is `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public`

You can create a new vhost for gitlab in apache with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.com/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You might also need to sudo a2enmod proxy_http

Comment: If you get permission errors like "You don't have permission to access /assets/logo-white-0b53cd4ea06811d79b3acd486384e047.png on this server." then you need "Require all granted" in the <Location>

Comment: my unicorn process name is config.ru, so I subjet to use netstat -pant | grep 8080

Comment: @themadmax, you can use netstat -pant and grep for 8080 if unicorn runs on that specific port.

Comment: How do you get gitlab-ce to not start nginx? I upgraded gitlab and it hijacked port 80 with nginx, preventing my existing Apache instance from starting. gitlab _really_ doesn't want to share a server with existing services.

Comment: @arclight this really depends on your OS. It could be as easy as disabling nginx to start at startup or stop it manually: `service nginx stop`

Comment: You misunderstand. Installing gitlab defaults to installing & configuring nginx on port 80 which interferes with the existing Apache instance on port 80. I know how to turn off nginx; I just don't want nginx installed or configured _at all_ as part of the gitlab installation. There's no warning in the docs that the gitlab installation is completely incompatible with traditional one-webserver-multiple-app setups and that it expects to own the whole box. The behavior is unexpected and rude.

Comment: @arclight, if you install from source, you can pick your preferred web server, but I think that you can do that even if you did choose to use the omnibus package. Maybe you could just uninstall nginx and create a new vhost in apache :)

Comment: you may need `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: I have modified /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf and added Alias /gitlab "/var/www/gitlab" with directory directive. When I try to access it via https://example.com/gitlab it does not work / does not load homepage but https://example.com/gitlab/deploy.html works well. How to access Gitlab first page?

Comment: For apache24 `Order deny,allow` and `Allow from all` Must be replaced by `Require all granted`

Comment: @arclight I know this is way after the fact but I got stuck on the samething for a day. You have to disable it inside the gitlab setup, gitlab.rb I took me a couple tries but, locate the `nginx['enable']` line and set it to false and remove the leading hashtag.

Comment: @mark-carpenter-jr
This is good, but here are all the steps from manual:
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
(for  omnibus-gitlab).
However, even after that, I needed to 
`gitlab-ctl restart`
And restart apache, than unicorn started to be active on port 8080 and apache did a proxy as @bogdan-t wrote for the virtualhost.
However, I think it is better to have gitlab on separate server, recommendation is to have a 2 CPU and 4 GB RAM - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html

Comment: @frank_108 those docs are way more complete now than they were over 2 years ago. Good looking out though. Currently I am in the process of migrating of migrating gitlab to docker. Much more straight forward and easier to proxy.

Answer (score 12):

I followed this article http://eserdeniz.fr/articles/view/4/installer-gitlab-sous-debian-7-avec-nginx-et-mysql and it worked but I needed apache instead of nginx.

After having much troubles configuring apache2 with gitlab-ce 7.9.0.rc3, I looked into apache documentation, regarding the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directive.

I solved my problems with this vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName gitlab.me

            # those options below are recommanded by apache, dealing with the simple Proxy we need for gitlab
            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

            # here we don't want to proxify the requests for the existing assets in gitlab's public directory
            ProxyPassMatch ^(/[^/]+\.(html|png|ico|css|txt))$ !
            ProxyPass /assets !

            # here we "redirect" the requests for http://gitlab.me/ to http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

            # here we "rewrite" the redirections form unicorn for http://127.0.0.1:8080/ into http://gitlab.me/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

            # And of course the DocumentRoot to handle the assets requests
            DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public/

            # In the last versions of apache, there is a deny,allow default order so we put those two sections to prevent 'client denied by server configuration' 403 error

            <Directory /home/git/gitlab/public/>
                    # apache 2.2
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all

                    # apache 2.4
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

            <Location />
                    # apache 2.2
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all

                    # apache 2.4
                    Require all granted
            </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Now it's blazing fast !!

Hoping this will help !

Answer (score 3):

On *Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)* with Omnibus 8.5.0 (apt-get) version:

GitLab Configuration

```
# cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.fr'
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

Apache2 Configuration

```
# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf  | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.example.fr
  ServerSignature Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.fr/
  </Location>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Netstat output

```
# netstat -pant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11849/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23736/config.ru
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8181          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26061/gitlab-workho
```

Source

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf

http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

Answer (score 2):

If you have HTTP git access problem look this configuration:

```
# cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.fr'
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_git_http_server['listen_addr'] = "localhost:8282"
```

and apache2 configuration:

```
# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gitlab.example.fr
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerSignature Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ProxyPassMatch ^(/[^/]+\.(html|png|ico|css|txt))$ !
        ProxyPass /assets !
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule /[-\/\w\.]+\.git\/ http://127.0.0.1:8282%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
        DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
            <Directory /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            <Location />
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apply changes:

```
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
# service apache2 reload
```

From https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2669#note_2176671

Answer (score 2):

For recent travelers with **GitLab 10.X.X** have a look at [this repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache). You can find Apache2 configuration files as well as instructions there to get GitLab running solely with Apache2 and NGINX disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Installation from source. gitlab 7.4.5

Unicorn is listening 9095. Apache is 2.2.9 and  I am not using https.

```
System information
System:         CentOS 6.7
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.11.2
Rake Version:   10.3.2
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.4.5
Revision:       19d572e
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            http://gitlab.example.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.example.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.example.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.0.1
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

Modify [configuration file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/apache-old/web-server/apache/gitlab-8.0-apache2.2.conf) of apache 2.2 works for me.

Another old configuration file for gitlab 6.0 is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/apache-old/web-server/apache/gitlab.conf) which also works for me.

```
#This configuration has been tested on GitLab 8.0.0
#Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and gitlab-git-http-server is listening on port 8181.
#To allow gitlab-git-http-server to listen on port 8181, edit or create /etc/default/gitlab and change or add the following:
#gitlab_git_http_server_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr localhost:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8080"

#Module dependencies
#  mod_rewrite
#  mod_proxy
#  mod_proxy_http
# HTTP Configuration
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
    # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
    #AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    <Location />
        #Require all granted
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        #Allow forwarding to gitlab-git-http-server
        #ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
        #Allow forwarding to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn)
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9095
        ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.com/
    </Location>

  #apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on
  #Forward these requests to gitlab-git-http-server
  #Forward these requests to gitlab-git-http-server
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive.* [OR]
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive.* [OR]
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$
  #RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  #Forward any other requests to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn)
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:9095%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog  logs/gitlab.example.com_error.log
  CustomLog logs/gitlab.example.com_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog logs/gitlab.example.com_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog logs/gitlab.example.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Hope useful for someone who installation from source with old edtion of gitlab.

Comment: Thank you for the most helpful links. This helped me with apache rewrite rules to proxy properly to both unicorn and workhorse.

Answer (score 1):

I just spend half a day figuring out why gitlab was giving me error 422 and complaining about CSRF tokens in the logs of gitlab-rails production.log.

It turns out I had to add this to apache config:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
```

In my case gitlab was installed from deb package and Apache is running on HTTPS.

Comment: I must add there also `RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'`

Answer (score 0):

Using @pincoded's answer, I was able to get GitLab up and running but when pushing changes I always received a 500 error.

Then I used the official config for apache provided by GitLab in @themadmax's answer. The problem here that the server was never reachable and after some time it produced a 502 error.

My solution:
Using [the official solution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf) by GitLab (be careful, remember to choose the SSL config in this link, if you run GitLab SSL only) BUT following [this forum entry](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-500-when-pull-or-clone/6058) I had to turn nginx ON again.

So in the end my config looked like this:

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://YOUR_SERVER_FQDN/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

</VirtualHost>
```

gitlab.ru:

```
# nginx['enable'] = false # this defaults to true
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
```