# Running GitLab from Apache subdirectory

Tags: git, apache, gitlab, subdirectory

I have installed Debian Wheezy and Git + GitLab. I managed to switch GitLab from using nginx to Apache in .rb file. Now I want to use GitLab with link like http://mylocalhost/gitlab, not from root link. I found this article about configuring apache for gitlab but it is about root dir using: [GitLab 7.2.1 with Apache Server instead of Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785903/gitlab-7-2-1-with-apache-server-instead-of-nginx)

Can someone explain what should I configure in order to access GitLab like http://mylocalhost/gitlab ?