# ISPCONFIG 3 and GITLAB

Tags: apache, debian, gitlab, ispconfig

I have my gitlab working locally, but somehow i cannot access it externally. Can't figure out the problem. I'm running Debian 8 system.

Current conf files :

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_url = "http://127.0.0.1:9999"
external_url "http://gitlab.example.ee"

gitlab_rails['gitlab_host'] = "gitlab.example.ee"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "gitlab@example.ee"
gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = "http://localhost:9999"

web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

unicorn['port'] = "9999"
nginx['enable'] = false
```

apache vhost (/etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
ServerAdmin info@example.ee
DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
ServerName gitlab.example.ee
ServerAlias gitlab.example.ee
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location />

    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted

    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.example.ee/
</Location>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* http://localhost:9999%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
ErrorLog  /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.error.log
CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.forwarded.log common_forwarded
CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.access.log combined env=!dontlog
CustomLog /${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? If so please post the solution.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ensure that your firewall is not blocking connections to port 9999. On Ubuntu you might need to do something like:

```
sudo ufw allow 9999/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a few years old, but I've been playing with a similar setup recently (but without the ISPConfig installation).  Throwing in my 2 cents for others who may run across this (this is my first time answering, so take it easy on me).

**NOTE** The op has not specified the version of GitLab being used.  More recent versions of GitLab are probably using newer versions of `gitlab.rb` so I'm not sure if that will make a difference.

**NOTE 2** I have found great information directly from GitLab at this site: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server. This is basically a copy and paste, but I'm throwing in my own notes to help out where I had issues as a complete n00b.

> 1. Disable bundled Nginx
>
> In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` set:
>
> ```
> nginx['enable'] = false
> ```
>
> 2. Set the username of the non-bundled web-server user
>
> By default, omnibus-gitlab has no default setting for the external
>   webserver user, you have to specify it in the configuration. For
>   Debian/Ubuntu the default user is `www-data` for both Apache/Nginx
>   whereas for RHEL/CentOS the Nginx user is nginx.
>
> Note: Make sure you have first installed Apache/Nginx so the webserver
>   user is created, otherwise omnibus will fail while reconfiguring.
>
> Let's say for example that the webserver user is www-data. In
>   /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb set:
>
> ```
> web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
> ```
>
> Note: This setting is an array so you can specify more than one user
>   to be added to gitlab-www group.  ***Personal Note:*** Please pay
>   close attention to the single-quotes and the array here.  While
>   developing, I've rebuild my gitlab server multiple times and entered
>   in JUST a string or JUST an array and both will fail.  The Chef script
>   will use this value to set up file permissions for its internal
>   directories, so Apache will not be able to write to files if this is
>   not correct.
>
> Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.
>
> Note: if you are using SELinux and your web server runs under a
>   restricted SELinux profile you may have to loosen the restrictions on
>   your web server.
>
> *Note: make sure that the webserver user has the correct permissions on all directories used by external web-server, otherwise you will
>   receive failed (XX: Permission denied) while reading upstream errors.
>
> 3. Add the non-bundled web-server to the list of trusted proxies (***OPTIONAL:*** This is only required if your web server is on a
>      different machine from your gitlab instance)
>
> Normally, omnibus-gitlab defaults the list of trusted proxies to the
>   what was configured in the real_ip module for the bundled NGINX.
>
> For non-bundled web-servers the list needs to be configured directly,
>   and should include the IP address of your web-server if it not on the
>   same machine as GitLab. Otherwise users will be shown as being signed
>   in from your web-server's IP address.
>
> ```
> gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = [ '192.168.1.0/24', '192.168.2.1', '2001:0db8::/32' ]
> ```
>
> 4. (Optional) Set the right gitlab-workhorse settings if using Apache ***PERSONAL NOTE:*** I believe this is the missing config from the op's question.
>
> Note: The values below were added in GitLab 8.2, make sure you have
>   the latest version installed.
>
> Apache cannot connect to a UNIX socket but instead needs to connect to
>   a TCP Port. To allow gitlab-workhorse to listen on TCP (by default
>   port `8181`) edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:
>
> ```
> gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
> gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
> ```
>
> Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.
>
> 5. Download the right web server configs
>
> Go to [GitLab recipes repository](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server) and look for the omnibus configs
>   in the webserver directory of your choice. Make sure you pick the
>   right configuration file depending whether you choose to serve GitLab
>   with SSL or not. The only thing you need to change is YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
>   with your own FQDN and if you use SSL, the location where your SSL
>   keys currently reside. You also might need to change the location of
>   your log files.

For the sake of completeness, here is an example of the Apache v2.4 config without the SSL configuration: ***READ THE COMMENTS:*** If you followed my above notes, in step 4 the gitlab_workhorse has already been configured to listen on tcp instead of a unix socket so that line may be ignored.  ***DO NOT IGNORE*** the module dependencies!  These are required for Apache to be able to proxy requests to your gitlab instance.  On Ubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04.4, but I believe most other Ubuntu version react the same), these modules can be activated using `sudo a2enmod rewrite proxy proxy_http`.

```
# This configuration has been tested on GitLab 8.2
# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
# listen on port 8181, edit or create /etc/default/gitlab and change or add the following:
#
# gitlab_workhorse_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr 127.0.0.1:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8080"
#
#Module dependencies
# mod_rewrite
# mod_proxy
# mod_proxy_http
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://YOUR_SERVER_FQDN/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This config file will not work with a simple copy and paste!

1. Find and replace "YOUR_SERVER_FQDN" with the Fully Qualified Domain Name of your gitlab instance.  Per the op's question, this would be `http://gitlab.example.ee`, but should basically match the value of `external_url` from your `gitlab.rb` file.
2. Find and replace "httpd" with "apache".  The config was not designed with a Ubuntu server in mind and the appropriate directory is called "apache".  I would assume you could also use ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}, but I have not tested this myself.

For a basic setup, this should work fine.  I would highly recommend looking into using the SSL setup (documentation can be found at the links provided).  Even if you don't need a secure setup (maybe this is an internal server), other features in the omnibus, like Mattermost, are prone to throw errors without SSL enabled (and not with a self-signed certificate).