# Invalid Command 'RewriteEngine' but mod_rewrite is enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gitlab

I am setting up a gitlab site with this [conf file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/raw/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf)

But this error arise:

```
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I have install apache 2.4.20 from source.  And forgot that I have installed 2.4.7 with `apt-get`.  Right now `apache -v` shows `2.4.7` though.

I have followed a lot of solutions but they do not work:

> Inside the httpd.conf file uncomment the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (remove the pound '#' sign from in front of the line)

[Apache2 ProxyPass for Rails App Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab)

I have check the rewrite modules and it is there; `a2enmod rewrite` is enabled and `service apache2 restart` worked without the `gitlab.conf` file.

But with `gitlab.conf`, this error appear `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'`?

Comment: Conditions and rules should be used in the `Directory` context, not the `VirtualHost` context. I've never tried it in the `Location` context, so I don't know what result that will yield.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue using Vagrant to setup a VM.
I finally resolved this by setting the ip for the client in the Vagrantfile configs:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.8"
```

Then adding to the local /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.68.8    namespace.dev
```