# Gitlab-CE Apache2.4 SSL redirect to different site not the gitlab workhorse

Tags: apache, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have recently attempted to move my gitlab-ce (version 8.13.6) instance over to my Apache web server (version 2.4.18). It works fine on HTTP however when trying to setup SSL using Lets Encrypt certificates. It redirects me to one of my other Apache sites (the default one) and not the gitlab workhorse. Any idea why it is doing this? And how to make it redirect to gitlab? Please find my site configuration below:

```
# This configuration has been tested on GitLab 8.2
# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
# listen on port 8181, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and change the following:
#
# gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
# gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
#
#Module dependencies
# mod_rewrite
# mod_ssl
# mod_proxy
# mod_proxy_http
# mod_headers

# This section is only needed if you want to redirect http traffic to https.
# You can live without it but clients will have to type in https:// to reach gitlab.
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.bancey.net
  ServerSignature Off

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  #strong encryption ciphers only
  #see ciphers(1) http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
  Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"
  SSLCompression Off
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain

  ServerName gitlab.bancey.net
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.bancey.net/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Don't escape encoded characters in api requests
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /etc/apache2/logs/gitlab.bancey.net.error.log
  CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/gitlab.bancey.net.forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/gitlab.bancey.net.access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/gitlab.bancey.net.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: http://gitlab.bancey.net redirects to its https URL (https://gitlab.bancey.net) for me in IE11, Edge, Chrome. What browser or tool are you using to connect? As SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gitlab.bancey.net) indicates, the site will work in clients that support SNI.

Comment: @AnandBhat Thanks, the problem being the page that it displays is not the Apache site that it should be, it should be showing the gitlab login. Like it does when I use http instead of https. It seems to be ignoring the rewrite ruels that should be sending my requests to the gitlab workhorse.

Comment: Are you seeing something other that this: https://i.imgur.com/lNODEav.png

Comment: @AnandBhat I was, disabling and re enabling the Apache site configuration seemed to have fixed it. Thanks for your help :)