# Running two websites on one apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, gitlab, vhosts, openproject

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a server and installed GitLab and OpenProject on it. However since I installed GitLab I can't access my OpenProject anymore, I've tried to forward it to a different port using the apache2 configs but it wouldn't work.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**:

```
# This configuration has been tested on GitLab 8.2
# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
# listen on port 8181, edit or create /etc/default/gitlab and change or add the following:
#
# gitlab_workhorse_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr 127.0.0.1:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8080"
#
#Module dependencies
# mod_rewrite
# mod_proxy
# mod_proxy_http
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName YOUR_SERVER_FQDN
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://YOUR_SERVER_FQDN/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/logs/YOUR_SERVER_FQDN.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName euve252630.serverprofi24.de
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf**:

```
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName euve252630.serverprofi24.de
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public

  ProxyRequests off

  Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/vhost/*.conf

  # Can't use Location block since it would overshadow all the other proxypass directives on CentOS
  ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I have no clue what else I can do, thanks in advance!

*Note: I want GitLab on port 80 and OpenProject on Port 81*

EDIT: Both are running, it is just a matter of configuration
EIDT: found what was causing the sites not being displayed. Nginx server was running by default from gitlab bundle

Comment: Is Gitlab working correctly? How do you want to access Gitlab and OpenProject - example.com/gitlab and example.com/openproject?

Comment: @Justas gitlab is currently running under example.com | yes example..com/gitlab example.com/openproject would be best

Comment: You can modify Gitlab configuration with 'sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb' and set 'external_url 'https://example.com/gitlab''. I would use 80 port for both projects and set specific Apache redirect to /gitlab and /openproject

Comment: @Justas I edited the gitlab.rb file, how exactly do I redirect to /gitlab and /openproject ? Sorry for asking but I never did this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab was running Nginx server by default, disabled it so apache works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access both of the projects, it should be as simple as having both projects as 2 separate folders under webapps folder of apache, and accessing them via the name of the folder(localhost:8080/)

Comment: can I just change dir of them that easily?

Comment: I have multiple sites running on my local apache server. So inside webapps folder, I have these multiple sites. For eg: webapps/
Website1
Website2

Now on my browser, If I need Website1, I go localhost:8080/Website1. Same for other website

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this same issue. I changed gitlab port and restart gitlab and apache2 server gitlab working on port number 99 and make sure openproject install will ssl.

```
gitlab working on      : http://ip:99/users/sign_in
openproject working on : https://ip/openproject
```

**Steps :**

```
1. sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
2. change port number : external_url "http://IP:99"
3. sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
4. sudo gitlab-ctl restart 
5. sudo service apache2 restart
```