# gitlab with apache connection refused

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I'm having trouble getting gitlab working on my server.
The environnment is :
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Apache 2.4

I installed gitlab via the omnibus script, edited the gitlab.rb to make it work with apache, made a vhost dedicated, struggled a little with SSL certs, got it working, but am stuck with an error I'm unable to solve.

When I go to https://gitlab.mydomain.com/users/sign_in I have a nice 503.
the error log says :

```
[Tue Apr 18 16:58:56.556702 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 31966] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8181 (*) failed
[Tue Apr 18 16:58:56.556722 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 31966] [client 93.182.244.38:60339] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: https://gitlab.mydomain.com/users/sign_in
```

Here is the vhost used :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
  ServerSignature Off
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse https://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse https://gitlab.mydomain.com/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse
  RewriteRule .* https://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gitlab.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`gitlab-workhorse` [doesn't support SSL connections](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-workhorse/blob/master/README.md)

> Workhorse can handle some requests without involving Rails at all:
>   for example, Javascript files and CSS files are served straight
>   from disk.
>
> Workhorse can modify responses sent by Rails: for example if you use
>   send_file in Rails then gitlab-workhorse will open the file on
>   disk and send its contents as the response body to the client.
>
> Workhorse can take over requests after asking permission from Rails.
>   Example: handling git clone.
>
> Workhorse can modify requests before passing them to Rails. Example:
>   when handling a Git LFS upload Workhorse first asks permission from
>   Rails, then it stores the request body in a tempfile, then it sends
>   a modified request containing the tempfile path to Rails.
>
> Workhorse can manage long-lived WebSocket connections for Rails.
>   Example: handling the terminal websocket for environments.
>
> Workhorse does not connect to Postgres, only to Rails and (optionally) Redis.
>
> We assume that all requests that reach Workhorse pass through an
>   upstream proxy such as NGINX or Apache first.
>
> **Workhorse does not accept HTTPS connections.**
>
> Workhorse does not clean up idle client connections.
>
> We assume that all requests to Rails pass through Workhorse.